# Prove that $(S^2/\{\pm 1\})/S^1 \cong S^2$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm searching an homeomorphism between $S^2$ and the space $A=\dfrac{S^2/\{\pm 1\}}{S^1}$, where the numerator is the quotient space given by the group action by multiplication of $\{\pm 1\}$ on $S^2$, and then we collapse $S^1$ to a point.

Intuitively, I understand what's happening: $S^2/\{\pm 1\}$ is a "semisphere", and if we collapse its base (that is homeomorphic to $S^1$) to a point, we obtain $S^2$ again. The problem is that I don't know how to formalize it: I tried
$$S^2 \xrightarrow{\pi}S^2/\{\pm1\} \xrightarrow{\pi}A$$
but it doesn't work because is not injective. Then I tried to find an identification between $S^2/\{\pm 1\} \rightarrow A$ that respect the equivalence relation given by the collapsing of $S^1$, but it didn't go anywhere.

Comment: I believe $S^2/\{\pm 1\}$ is not a "semisphere", but a projective plane, but this does not really matter here.

Comment: There's another quick way to know this if you know about CW complexes: The numerator is $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and the denominator is its 1-skeleton $\mathbb{R}P^1 \cong S^1$, so in forming the quotient one ends up with a CW complex with a single 0-cell and a single 2-cell, hence the result is necessarily $S^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Using spherical coordinates $\theta, \phi$, where $\theta$ is the polar angle:

$$
f(\theta, \phi) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcr}
  (2\theta, \phi) & \;\;\mbox{when}\;\; & 0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}
\\
(2\pi - 2\theta, \pi+\phi) & \;\;\mbox{when}\;\; &\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \pi
\end{array}
\right\}
$$

The equator $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, a.k.a. $S_1$, gets mapped to the South pole $(\pi,0)$, and the opposite points
$(\theta,\phi)$ and $(\pi-\theta, \pi+\phi)$ are mapped to the same point
$(2\theta, \phi) = (2\pi+2\theta, 2\pi+\phi)$ thus ensuring bijectivity between
$S^2 / \{\pm 1\} / S^1$ and $S^2$.